# How can we use the current directory path(%~dp0) with 'ren' command in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, relative-path, batch-rename

I want to rename a file which is present in the sub directory and the known part of the file name is '**.log**'.
When I try something like below

**`ren  subdirectory\*.log*  file2.txt`**

or

**`ren  .\subdirectory\*.log*  file2.txt`**

I get error : **`The syntax of the command is incorrect.`**
I have two questions here:

1. Do I always need to give full path in [ren](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490987.aspx) command for file1?
2. If yes, then how can I we give the full path if I do not want to hard code it?

I got to know that we can use '**%~dp0**' to get the current directory path but I am not sure how to use it with 'ren'.

Comment: Try adding quotes: `ren "subdirectory/file1.txt" file2.txt`

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried with quotes and it worked! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding quotes will work:

```
ren  "subdirectory\*.log*"  file2.txt
```

or

```
ren  ".\subdirectory\*.log*"  file2.txt
```

Thanks [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use relative path also `/` is incorrect in windows, use `\` instead.

If you want to search which relative path is correct, use the command `dir`

example:

```
dir .\
dir ..\..\
dir \
dir .
dir ..
```

**Update**

> `ren  subdirectory\*.log*  file2.txt`

Your rename mask seems **dangerous**!

I don't know if you can rename many files with mask wildcard into the same name. I think it will override every files into one, or at least it will concatenate into single file but not sure. 
If you want to see some examples of renaming mask, see this: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/a/475875/485351)

**UPDATE**

Small batch to see your mask in action:

```
@echo off

md Somefolder
echo some content into _file1.log>_file1.log
echo some content into _file2.log>_file2.log
echo some content into _file3.log>_file3.log
echo some content into _file999.log>_file999.log

dir Somefolder
pause>NUL

REM Correct
ren Somefolder\_file???.log _file???.txt
dir Somefolder
pause>NUL

REM Incorrect because it override _file???.txt into one _file1.log
ren Somefolder\_file???.txt _file1.log
dir Somefolder

pause
```

Comment: It's interesting though that `/` can be used to launch programs when quoted: `"c:/windows/explorer"` will launch Explorer.

Comment: @wOxxOm not on my windows. example: `type ../somefile.txt` getting error instead of `type ..\somefile.txt`

Comment: Yep, I've edited the comment as my memory failed me at first.

Comment: @Paul sorry for my mistake. I tried back slash only but mistakenly updated forward slash in the question. I updated the question. BTW thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Paul thanx for detailed explanation. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove extensions for all files *.log with relative path

```
rename ".\folder1\subfolder1\*.log" *.
```