# How to create .bat file that will delete one txt file from folder and rename other?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need .bat file that will be capable to delete one txt file called 0.txt from folder and after deletion it will pick up next txt file (with random name) from same folder and rename it to 0.txt. 
And again when i start the .bat file it will delete first the 0.txt and chose another txt file from folder and rename it to 0.txt

I got from one dude this

```
@echo off 
if exist 0.txt del 0.txt 
dir /b *.txt > %temp%\~txt.tmp 
for /f "delims=" %%a in (%temp%\~txt.tmp) do set file=%%a & goto RenOne
:RenOne 
ren "%file%" 0.txt 
del %temp%\~txt.tmp 
exit /b
```

but after the file is deleted the new 0.txt is not created (no file is renamed)

Comment: What have you tried so far? please remember that SO is not a coding service...

Comment: Even if you don't code yourself there are [many similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+random+file), please use search, find the most similar solution, try it, then if it won't work edit the question, add a link to that solution and describe what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: I got from one dude this:
@echo off 
if exist 0.txt del 0.txt 
dir /b *.txt > %temp%\~txt.tmp 

for /f "delims=" %%a in (%temp%\~txt.tmp) do set file=%%a & goto RenOne 

:RenOne 
ren "%file%" 0.txt 
del %temp%\~txt.tmp 
exit /b
after the file is deleted the new 0.txt is not created (no file is renamed)

Comment: where does `%file%` get its value? Maybe start there...

Comment: renaming many *.txt into one name will override every *.txt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32462803/how-can-we-use-the-current-directory-pathdp0-with-ren-command-in-a-batch-f/32463133#32463133 Also not sure goto RenOne will work here.. You have to put it one line after DO

Comment: Don't use `goto` in a `for` loop, that's just asking for error

Comment: I have zero experiences with coding so i have no idea what to do with it

Comment: The essential problem with your code is the space here breaks the rename command `%%a &` but the code is not robust to long filename elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is untested:

```
@echo off 
if exist "0.txt" del "0.txt"
for %%a in (*.txt) do set "file=%%a"
ren "%file%" "0.txt"
```

Comment: @JankoHrasko Just adding that the file it picks next is always the last one in the list on NTFS drives, and on FAT32 drives it is unpredictable as the directory list is changeable.

Comment: Thats okey no need to be ordered anyhow just one file from the directory to be renamed and it works so thanks again